# Python save JSON response daily, based on date range

Tags: python, json, date

For example, we have the date range (START=2019-01-01, END=2019-03-01)

Then we have 2 functions:

1) A process which do something and save response to the file:

```
def job_function():
     # Date are part of parameters like this:
        dates.gt({}).lt({})'.format(START,END),
     # Here should be the code which ends up with :
        responseMain = requests.get(urlMain, params=params, headers=headers).json()
        with open(FILE_NAME, "a+") as outfile:
             outfile.write(json.dumps(responseMain))
```

2) Main one:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

  for (something here? or something inside the function 1??) 
     sm_data(START,END)
```

I need to modify function 1, that it will take the main date range and will run continuously by processing each day.

E.G.
IF date range is (START=2019-01-01, END=2019-03-01)

Function 1 will continuously run with this date:

- START=2019-01-01, END=2019-01-02
- START=2019-01-02, END=2019-01-03
- START=2019-01-03, END=2019-01-04
- START=2019-01-04, END=2019-01-05
- START=2019-01-05, END=2019-01-06
- START=2019-01-06, END=2019-01-07
- START=2019-01-07, END=2019-01-08
- START=2019-01-08, END=2019-01-09

Until- START=2019-02-28, END=2019-03-01

And while processing, data will append to the same file

**EDIT 1:** This is a workaround to pull data PER DAY within time range instead of SUM PER FULL DATE RANGE

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking. You want to run the script for a date range, and invoke the function on 1 day ranges in a loop? If so, why not just send the SATRT and END in from main (using argparse or similar) and then loop  over the days?

Comment: @doctorlove sorry my fault, perfectly understand you... if I pass the date range as I explained, I will receive result PER DAY, if I will put the FULL DATE RANGE, will receive result total for 3 months, this API does not support dimensions.. so this is like a workaround. If you have any alternatives for how to make it PER DAY, I will be happy with any solution...

Comment: What are `START` and `END`? Strings, datetime.date objects, other?

Comment: @SergeBallesta String Or can be used this - `(datetime.date.today()).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I shall assume here that your code contains a place where two variables exist:
START=2019-01-01 and END=2019-03-01.

You have just to save them and write a loop that sets them for each iteration and calls `sm_data`:

```
# ok START and END exist here
# convert them to datetime.date
fmt = '%Y-%m-%d'
cur = datetime.datetime.strptime(START, fmt).date()
end = datetime.datetime.strptime(END, fmt).date()
# prepare the loop:
delta = datetime.timedelta(days=1)
while cur < end:
    START = cur.strftime(fmt)      # current date
    cur += delta                   # next day
    END = cur.strftime(fmt)
    sm_data(START, END)
```